# How to prevent a job from running when the branch is different from release/

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, jobs

I am working with gitlab ci and I need the job to run only when the branch is release/ and if it is any other branch the job will not run.

I have tried to do it in many ways but none of them works, I would appreciate if you could help me, because I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [rules block](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) and [common if clauses for rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules).

For your specific question adding the following should work:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release/
```